# Etag support for S/4 EX

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Etag is supported in SDK: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v4-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/#handling-of-etags

So experimenting it by using BusinessPartner entity in S/4 EX.

But seems there's no If-Match header:

[image: log capture]

How come the header doesn't show up - any prerequisite with etag?

(entering on behalf of the implementation partner team)

---

I checked the VersionIdentifier of the response and it was not set to a value.
I also checked the response's JSON __metadeta and header, but there were no values that appeared to correspond to the ETag value.

[Code]

```
BusinessPartner bp1 = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService().getBusinessPartnerByKey(bpId).execute(dest);
log.debug("get 1: {}", bp1);
log.debug("get 1 VersionIdentifier: {}", bp1.getVersionIdentifier());

bp1.setOrganizationBPName1("SCP Update 1st:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
ODataUpdateResult result1 = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService().updateBusinessPartner(bp1).execute(dest);
log.debug("Update1 Http Status: {}", result1.getHttpStatusCode());

bp1.setOrganizationBPName1("SCP Update 2nd:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
bp1.setVersionIdentifier("dummy");
ODataUpdateResult result2 = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService().updateBusinessPartner(bp1).execute(dest);
log.debug("Update2 Http Status: {}", result2.getHttpStatusCode());
```

[Log]

```
get 1: BusinessPartner(super=VdmObject(customFields={}, changedOriginal...
get 1 VersionIdentifier: None
Update1 Http Status: 204
Update2 Http Status: 204
```

[GET Response JSON(__metadata) / Response Header]
(It has masked the IP address.)

```
"__metadata": {
    "id": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxxx/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('1000001')",
    "uri": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxxx/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner('1000001')",
    "type": "API_BUSINESS_PARTNER.A_BusinessPartnerType"
},
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 3152
dataserviceversion: 2.0
sap-metadata-last-modified: Thu, 14 May 2020 23:58:07 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache
sap-processing-info: ODataBEP=,crp=,RAL=,st=,MedCacheHub=SHM,codeployed=X,softstate=
sap-server: true
sap-perf-fesrec: 243070.000000
```

I tried setting the VersionIdentifier to a meaningless value in my test code (2nd update).
The update process seems to be successful, although the request header now has "If-Match" added to it.
(I was expecting the update to fail because the values never match, so I was hoping the update would fail.)

[2nd Update(setVersionIdenfifier)]
(It has masked some of the values.)

```
PATCH http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxxx/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner(BusinessPartner='1000001') HTTP/1.1
x-csrf-token: xxx
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
If-Match: dummy
Authorization: Basic xxx
SAP-Connectivity-SCC-Location_ID: xxx
Proxy-Authorization: Bearer xxx
sap-language: en
sap-client: xxx
Content-Length: 55
```

---

Comment: Are you fetching the entity explicitly before doing a PATCH update?Can you please add the code snippet that you use to make the PATCH call?

Comment: The update request itself uses the version identifier / ETag. But I assume the entity does not get populated with the identifier from the _getByKey_ request. You can test this with `bp1.getVersionIdentifier()` - what does it return?

In order to solve the issue, can you please check in your logs for the GET request, whether ETag is part of the JSON response *payload*, inside `__metadata` object. Is the ETag part of the HTTP response *header*? Please check both origins and let us know. Unfortunately some services behave differently than others.

Comment: (Updating the question post on behalf of the implementation partner)

Comment: Thanks for the additional details! From the listings _"GET Response JSON(__metadata) / Response Header"_ I conclude that the ETag (version identifier) is **not** part of the service get-by-key response, neither in HTTP header nor in JSON payload. If you confirm that this is true, than I assume for some reason this feature was switched off(?). Usually we'd expect the feature to be enabled for _Business Partner_ service. When it's not enabled, then we should consider raising a BCP incident and ask the administrators.

Answer (score 0):

If ETags are not part of OData service responses, then you should approach the IT/administrators who maintain the S/4 backend. The [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/) is only consuming the OData service. Unfortunately it can't leverage ETag support if it's disabled.

Comment: Hi Alex, do you come up with any suggestion what OData service would be ETag compliant on S/4? It's likely that Business Partner is not implementing ETag yet.